# $f_*$ be a morphism of chain complex, if $Ker(f_*)$ and $Coker(f_*)$ are exacte complex, then $H_n(f_*)$ is a isomorphism for all $n$.

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $f_*:C_*\rightarrow C_*'$ be a morphism of chain complex. Show that, if $Ker(f_*)$ and $Coker(f_*)$ are exacte complex, then $H_n(f_*)$ is a isomorphism for all $n$.

The notation I'm using is: $d_i:C_i\rightarrow C_{i-1}$ and $d_i':C_i'\rightarrow C_{i-1}' $, both for all $  i\in \{ 1,\cdots , n \}$.

Well, this is what I understand from this:

I have this two exacte sequences of kernels and cokernels and I have to show that

$$H_n(f_*):H_n(C_*)\rightarrow H_n(C_*') $$
$$H_n(f_*):Ker(d_n)/Im(d_{n+1})\rightarrow Ker(d_n')/Im(d_{n+1}')$$
$$z_n+Im(d_{n+1})\mapsto f_n(z_n)+Im(d_{n+1}')$$
is an isomorphism. But I can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $ker(f)$ is exact, $C \to C/ker(f)$ is a quasi-iso. Since $0 \to C/ker(f) \to C' \to coker(f) \to 0$ is a short exact sequence of chain complexes, $C\to C/ker(f) \to C'$ is a quasi-iso.